# Onelogin API to add applications to user

Tags: java, onelogin

Is there an API to add applications to the user.

I am able to fetch apps for the user via,

GET - https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/users/{user-id}/apps

Couldn't find the API to add apps to a user

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to assign applications to a Role in the admin console and then use the APIs to set the roles for the user.

This, in turn grants the user access to the application assigned to the role.

For more info see: https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/assign-role-to-user